# Error in setValues : std::bad_alloc ao executar a função aggregate em um arquivo raster

Tags: r

Ao executar a função aggregate para reduzir a resolução de um arquivo raster estou recebendo o erro abaixo,

```
Error in setValues(out, .Call("_raster_aggregate_fun", x, dims, as.integer(na.rm), : std::bad_alloc.
```

O comando utilizado foi,

```
DEM2 <- aggregate(DEM, fact=2, fun=mean, expand=FALSE, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Como resolver isso ?

a versão que estou usando é o R-3.4.3 instalado no OpenSUSE Leap 42.3 64Bits, em um laptop com processador core i5 e 8GB de RAM.

Comment: Você está usando Windows? Rstudio? Qual o tamanho do objeto (`object.size(dados)`)?Esse erro parece ser associado à alocação de memória de arquivos muito grandes. Edite sua pergunta com partes do dados `dput(head(dados))` para que possamos testar se seu código esta correto.

Comment: esta vindo de um bd a variável DEM,  usou attach()?

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra maneira sem usar a função aggregate é:

```
require(raster)

# criando um raster com dados aleatórios
r <- matrix(runif(100),nrow=10,ncol=10)
r <- raster(r)

# cria um raster com resolucao menor (aggregate)
r1 <- raster(nrow=dim(r)[1]/2, ncol=dim(r)[2]/2, ext=extent(r)) # resolucao diminui pela metade
r1 <- resample(r, r1, method="ngb") # ngb se os dados forem categoricos

r2 <- resample(r, r1, method="bilinear") # se os dados forem tipo gradiente


par(mfrow = c(3, 1))  # 3 linhas com um grafico cada
plot(r, main='raster original')
plot(r1, main='menor resolucao por ngb')
plot(r2, main='menor resolucao por bilinear')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]